# How can I send a number twice For egg 99 in Selenium in a text box

Tags: selenium, appium-android

I am trying to insert a phone number which is 9986 .When I inspect Element , Selenium is taking only one "9'". How to type another 9 ?

```
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='9']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='9']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='8']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='6']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='7']")).click();
```

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: I am using Selenium and Appium . I am not using any html here